# Plot rank variables with low values high on the y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, reverse, rank

Hi I have a molten data set that contains median rankings of different groups of a categorical variable.  Because it is ranking, I'd like to actually come up with a graph that plots 1s, and 2s at the top end of the y-axis to convey that they are high rankings, not low rankings. Currently, the plot that I create shows the information with 1s and 2s at the low end of the y-axis, which of course makes sense if you were plotting a traditional continuous variable where higher values are, well, higher. I've tried reversing the values but that does a weird thing with the facets order.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
#Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
#My data
test<-    structure(list(d3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L,       
1L, 2L,  3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Professional     
journalist",  
"Elected politician", "Online blogger"), class = "factor"), variable = 
structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
7L,  7L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Information", "Accessible", "Debate",  
"Officials", "Responsive", "Trade-Offs", "Social"), class = "factor"),     
value = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 2.5, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4,     7, 6, 7, 5, 4, 
4)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), .Names = c("d3", "variable", "value"), class = 
"data.frame")

#Plot
ggplot(test, aes(x=d3,  y=value, group=d3))+geom_bar(stat='identity',     
aes(fill=d3))+facet_wrap(~variable)

#Try reversing the values of value
test$value2<-rev(test$value)

#Replotting
ggplot(test, aes(x=d3,  y=value2, group=d3))+geom_bar(stat='identity', 
aes(fill=d3))+facet_wrap(~variable)
```

This replotting seems to just move the facets around: "Information" is now showing the former values of "social", but under the heading of "information"

Comment: Have you tried `scale_y_reverse()`?

Comment: Yes, except there, I find the bars descend from the top, rather than the bottom. It might be a little better, but it still doesn't seem to communicate what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have in mind, setting the levels of value differently?

```
test$value <- factor(test$value, levels = c("7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"))

ggplot(test, aes(x=d3,  y=value, group=d3)) + geom_bar(stat ='identity',  aes(fill=d3)) + facet_wrap(~variable)]
```

[image]

Comment: So, that is exactly right. The only issue is that there is one median value of 2.5; coding value without that returns an NA (visible above).  I've recoded the value to add .5 values between each integer, but now it just looks wonky. The 2.5 level is the only one that shows up in the y-axis.  Thanks, this is almost 100% the way there.

Comment: I've had 0.5 values too, and ended up rounding them all up to whole numbers (especially since there were very few).  Would that suffice?  Alternatively, you can add the 2.5 to the levels argument, I believe.  Let me know if either approach works.